# Is this normal Xcode behavior

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uitextview, behavior

I have a **Text View** Object on my storyboard that doesn't seem to render correctly.

I've seen this often and didn't know if this was a bug or normal behavior as it only renders a few lines:

[image]

However when I double click on the object:

[image]

All is visible.

Any work arounds or should I submit a bug report on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal. When you double-click you edit the content that is bigger than the frame size.

It has always been like that, you can update the UITextView's frame.

Comment: But my frame size - is the entire view controller?